# How do I install fuse-ext2 to use with OSXFuse

Tags: install, filesystem

I'm trying to make Ext4 disk readable on mac OSX 10.10.5. I've already installed **OSXFuse**, I read on this site that I also needed to install **fuse-ext2**. I downloaded **fuse-ext2-master.zip** and unzipped it. It seems to contain source code files but no installation program. How am I supposed to use these files?

Answer (score 7):

The build from source how-to is available at the git homepage of [fuse-ext2](https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2). Please use the lines below though, because I had to make slight changes to get it working (e.g the libtool download source has been moved).

At least the appropriate [xcode-command-line-tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) and [OSXFuse](https://sourceforge.net/projects/osxfuse/) have to be installed.

Download the source from github and unzip the file. Then open Terminal.app and enter

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

assuming the fuse-ext2 file was unzipped there.

First you have to download, make and install several tools (m4, autoconf, automake, libtool, e2fsprogs). Then you can build fuse-ext2. This is all done using Terminal.app.

```
export PATH=/opt/gnu/bin:$PATH

mkdir gnu
cd gnu

# m4
curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/m4/m4-1.4.17.tar.gz
tar -zxvf m4-1.4.17.tar.gz 
cd m4-1.4.17
./configure --prefix=/opt/gnu
make -j 16
sudo make install
cd ../

# autoconf
curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
tar -zxvf autoconf-2.69.tar.gz 
cd autoconf-2.69
./configure --prefix=/opt/gnu
make
sudo make install
cd ../

# automake
curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.15.tar.gz
export PATH=/opt/gnu/bin:$PATH
tar -zxvf automake-1.15.tar.gz 
cd automake-1.15
./configure --prefix=/opt/gnu
make
sudo make install
cd ../

# libtool
curl -O http://ftp.hawo.stw.uni-erlangen.de/gnu/libtool/libtool-2.4.6.tar.gz
tar -zxvf libtool-2.4.6.tar.gz 
cd libtool-2.4.6
./configure --prefix=/opt/gnu
make
sudo make install
cd ../

# e2fsprogs
curl -O https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/tytso/e2fsprogs/v1.42.12/e2fsprogs-1.42.12.tar.gz
tar -zxvf e2fsprogs-1.42.12.tar.gz
cd e2fsprogs-1.42.12
./configure --prefix=/opt/gnu
make
sudo make install
sudo make install-libs
cd ../../

# fuse-ext2
cd fuse-ext2-master
export PATH=/opt/gnu/bin:$PATH
./autogen.sh
CFLAGS="-idirafter/opt/gnu/include -idirafter/usr/local/include/osxfuse/" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/gnu/lib -L/usr/local/lib" ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

All lines without a `#` have to be entered in Terminal and then executed by hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. You may use copy and paste.

---

An easier way is to install [brew](http://brew.sh/) and use these instructions below (also in Terminal).

```
brew doctor #repair everything you are warned about!
brew install homebrew/dupes/m4
brew install e2fsprogs automake autoconf libtool
cd ~/Downloads/fuse-ext2-master
./autogen.sh
CFLAGS="-idirafter/$(brew --prefix e2fsprogs)/include -idirafter/usr/local/include/osxfuse" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix e2fsprogs)/lib" ./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

---

After finishing either of the two methods all necessary files are installed (including a prefpane) and you should be able to r/w ext2/3/4.

Comment: Thanks for the help... but it didn't work. Here's what I got in my terminal window:  

make[3]: *** [install-exec-local] Error 1  
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2  
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1  
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1  
Studio-Mac:fuse-ext2-master michel$

Comment: Studio-Mac:~ michel$ echo PATH$
PATH$

Comment: @MichelGougeon sorry that was the wrong one: `echo $PATH` is the right one

Comment: I cannot expres how much I hate apple right now. I have to download a 2.6GB (xcode) program just to mount a filesystem and compile a driver myself? I'm on the brink of a nervous breakdown.

Comment: @BdN3504 Command line tools (160 MB) are sufficient. AppleID required though.

Comment: Hi @klanomath it seems that the above is not currently working for macos with M1 apple silicon. It failed with errors during "make" of fuse-ext2. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

@klanomath:  I had some issues working through your instructions.  Brew failed for me so I went back and worked through the longer instructions.  There were a few issues I had to resolve, but couldn't have been successful without your outstanding instructions!  Thank you.  My notes:

The link is broken for libtool. Had to use:

```
curl -O https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtool/libtool-2.4.6.tar.gz
```

Also had issue with needing needing get text which addressed with:

```
brew reinstall gettext
```

and

```
brew unlink gettext && brew link gettext --force
```

and Finally, I actually needed full Xcode install (so big) and then running the following command:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

---

I have compiled more code on a Mac than on Linux... didn't expect that... LOL